# JavaScript - trying to change colour of span elements when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css

I have a side bar nav that shows by clicking the button which is made up of span elements - it is currently white.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div id="sidebar-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS for the span:

```
div#sidebar-btn span{
        height: 1px;
        background:white;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display: block;
    }
```

Here is another class I have created in order for it turn black once the page has been scrolled down a certain amount, with the .toggleClass function. This is because there is a section of content once the user has scrolled and it has a white background - therefore the button won't show up because it's white too.

```
  div#sidebar-btn.black span{
        height: 1px;
        background:black;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display: block;
    }
```

Here is the Javascript that is attempting to toggle the class for the sidebar button for the class to change to 'black'.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(window).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50)  {  // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window 

                $("#sidebar-btn")(function(){
                    $("#sidebar-btn").toggleClass('black');
                });
             }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

It's not working. I'm good at HTML and CSS but not great at JavaScript, and there's clearly an error here. Not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the on scroll listener called every time scrollTop changed, so when the scrollTop more than 50, you start toggling the `black` class. Thats mean you toggled the black every single callback of the scroll listener. What you should do, is to check if the scrollTop more than 50 and then check also if your does not have the class `black` and add it, and if the scrollTop bellow 50 you have to check if your element have the class `black` and remove it.

#### Full Example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50)  {
      if(!$("#sidebar-btn").hasClass('black')){
        $("#sidebar-btn").addClass('black');
      }
    }else{
      if($("#sidebar-btn").hasClass('black')){
        $("#sidebar-btn").removeClass('black');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#sidebar-btn span{
  background: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

div#sidebar-btn.black span{
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-btn">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if statement try to omit the function declaration and use only the jQuery's toggleClass() method and it should work as desired.

Comment: Can you include the code that you are proposing in you answer.